# Form data not found in HTTP call

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

This is how the authentication is supposed to be.
POST https://DomainName/api/v1/authentication?username={username}&password={password}..
this is the typescript authentication call code

```
authenticate(url, payload){
let username: string = 'admin';
let password: string = 'password';
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
return this.http.post(server + url + addon, payload, { headers:headers });
```

this is the code for the form data

```
    // Getting data info from signing form
loginForm = new FormGroup({
username: new FormControl(null, ([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])),
password: new FormControl(null, ([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])),
})
```

the user data

```
// user data 
loginData={
username:'',
    password:'',
}

buildLoginData(){
    this.loginData.password = this.loginForm.controls['password'].value;
this.loginData.username = this.loginForm.controls['username'].value;
}
```

the sign in function

```
    signin(){
    this.loading =this.loadingCtrl.create({
  content:"Verifying Credentials ..."
});
this.loading.present();
    this.buildLoginData();
    console.log(this.loginData);
  this.http.store('authentication', this.loginData).subscribe((response)=>{
            // console.log(response);
            // console.log("*******************************************");
            // console.log(response['username']);
            localStorage.setItem('office_ID',response['officeId']);
            localStorage.setItem('user_ID', response['userId']);
            localStorage.setItem('username', response['username']);
            this.loading.dismissAll();
            this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);
  },error=>{
            this.loading.dismissAll();
                if(error.status === 401){
                    this.toastr.messenger('Wrong Username or Password');
                }else
    this.toastr.messenger('Login Failed!');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            alert("Error : " + error );
});    
}
```

Response log data

```
{"_body":"{\"developerMessage\":\"Invalid authentication details were 
passed in api request.\",\"httpStatusCode\":\"401\",\"defaultUserMessage 
\":\"Unauthenticated. Please login.\",\"userMessageGlobalisationCode
\":\"error.msg.not.authenticated\",\"errors
\":[]}","status":401,"ok":false,"statusText":"Unauthorized","headers":
{"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"type":2,"url":"https//x.x.x.x:xxxx/xxxxxxxxx/api/v1/authentication?tenantIdentifier=default"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Headers are immutable in Angular, because of this, in your code, they never actually leave the client.

Here's a fix:

```js
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
headers = headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Headers'. this is the response i'm getting.

Comment: Sorry, I just now saw that you are using the Headers class, not the HttpHeaders. What version of angular are you running?

Comment: this is the angular core in the ionic project "@angular/core": "4.1.3"